# Google App Script One Shot Authentication

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-apps-script, authorization

I'm trying to make my Google App Script/Google Spreadsheet a template. The only problem I'm having is with authentication. If you try to run any of the script it will authenticate itself but I need it to deploy itself as a WebApp. I'm using:

```
function startWebApp() {
//Setup the webapp service
var service = ScriptApp.getService();
service.enable(service.Restriction.ALL);
Logger.log("WebApp Started");
}
```

and when I run this from a menu I've created in the spreadsheet, so it has a nice front-end interface, it will ask to authorize but then the next time you run it (I've read that you need to run a function twice, once to authorize the script and the second time actually runs the function) you get

```
Your one shot authorization state is not valid. The script must be reauthorized. The script's reauthorization can be triggered by calling ScriptApp.invalidateAuth() and rerunning the script.
```

Is there a better way or different way to allow a script to publish itself or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reauthorize it. Be sure to separate function.

```
function inv(){
  ScriptApp.invalidateAuth();
}
```

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#invalidateAuth()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#invalidateAuth%28%29)